# highlight the row which has null value - jQuery (not working as expected)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When user click on GetData button, i'm getting the json data and displaying in the html table as shown in the demo.

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/I4XYY6CZohf7IS6wP8dR?p=preview

**Sometimes the value can be null** as it was for the loanNum variable shown below.

```
  var loanNum = [{ "code": "23432", "description": "23432" }, { "code": null, "description": null }];
```

If atleast one value is null for a specific row, **i want to highlight that entire row with red color** so that user knows that row has null value.I tried with the below code,
but the row which has null value is not highlighting with red color..

```
if(loanNum[i].code == null){
      console.log("row has null value");
      $(this).css({'background-color':'red'});
}
```

Any inputs would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated** This will goes through every fields ('code', 'description'), and find if any of that have null value.

```js
function submitData() {
        var flag = true;
        $('#loanTable input[type="text"]').val('');
        $('.mortgageType').val('');
        $('.order').val('');
        if (flag) {
            //values from backend
            var mortageType = [{ "code": "Home", "description": "Home" }, { "code": "Car", "description": "Car" }];
            var loanNum = [{ "code": "23432", "description": "23432" }, { "code": null, "description": null }];
            var status = [{ "code": "Approved", "description": "Approved" }, { "code": "Pending", "description": "Pending" }];
            var j = 0;
            //iterate and show the jsonData in the table2 when user click on submit button
            
            for (var i = 0; i < mortageType.length; i++) {
                j = j + 1;
                console.log("-- loanNum[i].code ---- " + loanNum[i].code);
                document.getElementById("mortageType" + j).value = mortageType[i].code;
                document.getElementById("loanNum" + j).innerText = loanNum[i].code;
                document.getElementById("status" + j).innerText = status[i].code;
                // Loop through all fields.
                Object.keys(loanNum[i]).forEach(function(key) {
                  // Check if any fields is null
                  if (loanNum[i][key] == null) {
                    $('#status' + j).parent().parent().css({'border':'red'});
                  }
                });
            } 
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<table class="loanTable" id="loanTable" border="1">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>    <label for="show"><span name="3765" maxlength="1"class="message">Year</span></label> </th> <!-- From Dealer -->
        <th>    <label for="show"><span name="568" maxlength="1" class="message">Mortgage Type</span>&nbsp;
            <span name="496" maxlength="1" class="message"></span>
        </label>
        </th>
        <th>    <label for="show"><span name="3702" maxlength="1" class="message">Loan Num</span></label> </th>
        <th>    <label for="show"><span name="2366" maxlength="1" class="message">Status</span></label> </th>
        <th>    <label for="show"><span name="179"  maxlength="1" class="message">Comments</span></label> </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="show" class="ddownlabels"></label> <!-- From Dealer -->
            <select id="year" name="year" disabled>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="cloneX10 indField">
                <label for="show" class="ddownlabels"></label> <!-- From Dealer -->
                <select id="mortageType1" name="mortageType1" class="mortgageType">
                  <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="Auto">Auto</option>
                    <option value="Home">Home</option>
                    <option value="Car">Car</option>
                </select>
                <input name="ord1" id="ord1" class="order">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td><div class="cloneX10 indField" id="loanNum1"></div></td>
        <td><div class="cloneX10 indField" id="status1"></div></td>
        <td><div class="cloneX10 indField" id="comments1"></div></td>
    </tr>

    <!--Second row-->
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="show" class="ddownlabels"></label> <!-- From Dealer -->
            <select id="year" name="year" disabled>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="cloneX10 indField">
                <label for="show" class="ddownlabels"></label> <!-- From Dealer -->
                <select id="mortageType2" name="mortageType2" class="mortgageType">
                  <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="Auto">Auto</option>
                    <option value="Home">Home</option>
                    <option value="Car">Car</option>
                </select>
                <input name="ord2" id="ord2"  class="order">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td><div class="cloneX10 indField" id="loanNum2"></div></td>
        <td><div class="cloneX10 indField" id="status2"></div></td>
        <td><div class="cloneX10 indField" id="comments2"></div></td>
    </tr>

    <!--Third Row-->
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="show" class="ddownlabels"></label> <!-- From Dealer -->
            <select id="year" name="year" disabled></select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="cloneX10 indField">
                <label for="show" class="ddownlabels"></label> <!-- From Dealer -->
                <select id="mortageType3" name="mortageType3" class="mortgageType">
                  <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="Auto">Auto</option>
                    <option value="Home">Home</option>
                    <option value="Car">Car</option>
                </select>
                <input name="ord3" id="ord3" class="order">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td><div class="cloneX10 indField" id="loanNum3"></div></td>
        <td><div class="cloneX10 indField" id="status3"></div></td>
        <td><div class="cloneX10 indField" id="comments3"></div></td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table><br>
<input type="submit" value="GetData" onclick="submitData()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. Can i highlight the row line with red color without highlighting entire row with red color..

Comment: Updated. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the update..I wonder if the code  if(loanNum[i].code == null){ //code to highlight null value row with red color } i have written is the best way to check for null, so if i have 10 columns/fields i need to check for each and every fields with an OR(||) condition. Is there any better approach to check for nulls other than which i have given?

Comment: Something like that? I not sure. Please check it out.

Answer (score 2):

you're targeting `$(this)` as though it is the current row, even though there is no reason for it to be (it is actually the window object). You need to select the row and then colour it red, this should do the trick:

`$('#loanTable tr')[j].style = "background-color:red"`

or if you want to stick to using jQuery's `css()` method:

`$($('#loanTable tr')[j]).css('background-colod','red')`

though I don't recommend it since it is unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: `$($('#loanTable tr')[j])` <-- **do not do this**  Take a moment to understand what your commands are doing.  You select elements, returning a jQuery object, you then get the `j` element from the jQuery object, which turns it into a DOM Element, you then take that element and create a new jQuery object from it.  Rather than using [j] in this case use `eq(j)` which will preserve the element as a jQuery object and then you don't have to stick it in `$()` again